# Como hacer una función con javascript que limpie un input si otro se esta guardando vacío?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo esta función que evalúa si dicho input esta vació que seria el principal (por así decirlo) y lo que quiero es que si esta vació que le de el valor de "0" al otro input esta seria mi función:

```
function validar(){
    var obra = document.getElementById("obra").value;
    var lim = document.getElementById("a").value;

    if(obra == ""){
        alert("Por favor agregue una mano de obra");
        lim.value ="0";
        return false
    }
}
```

No me hace el cambio no se que es lo que falta o que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: declara la variable `lim` de esta forma: `var lim = document.getElementById("a");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma como obtienes `lim`, solo estas selecionando el valor del input `a` y no el objeto. Por eso cuando haces `lim.value = "0";` no asigna nada porque `lim` en realidad es una cadena.

Dejo el mismo codigo, solo que al momento de obtener el elemento **`a`** he eliminado el `.value`. De esta forma podras asignarle un valor mas adelante.

```
function validar(){
    var obra = document.getElementById("obra").value;
    var lim = document.getElementById("a");

    if(obra == ""){
        alert("Por favor agregue una mano de obra");
        lim.value = "0";
        return false
    }
}
```

> [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById): Devuelve una referencia a un objeto [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element), o null si un elemento con el ID especificado no se encuentra en el documento.